# Binlogs vs sql dumps in MySQL

Tags: mysql, backup

I've been reading about mysql's binlogs and sql dumps, and I have a doubt: Is there any benefit in using binlogs instead of sql dumps?
  I know you can use binlogs for making incremental backups -something impossible to do with dumps-, but I wonder if there is another benefits with binlogs.

Bye! And thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I use a mixed approach for backups: automatic mysqldump during dawn and I keep binlogs to use as an incremental backup since last mysqldump.

But binlogs importance is greater than this: binlogs are also used do set MySQL master-slave replication as they keep the record of every statements that should be replicated to the slaves.

More info about MySQL binary logs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Marco!

Yes, I knew binlogs are used for master-slave replication, although I've never used it :-)

But my doubt was related exclusively to backups. If there is some kind of advantage in using binlogs over dumps or if they are complementary solutions.

Bye! And thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

with binlogs you can roll into any givent moment in past; not just day before, 2 days before etc [assuming you have daily backups]. this can be helpful especially in tracing some possible bugs in your apps using the db.

similarly to Marco i use full dumps+binlogs [for replication purpose and for tracing back].